Issue in Mongo Repositories with spring boot junit5 test and testcontainers
Facing issue of repositories in below test configuration.

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;

    @SpringBootTest
    @TestConfiguration
    public class MongoTestConfig {
        static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.4.2")
                .withExposedPorts(27017)
            .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());

    static {
        mongoDBContainer.start();
    }

    // Method to get the MongoDB connection URL with a specified database name
    private String getMongoUrl(String dbName) {
        return String.format("mongodb://%s:%d/%s",
                mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress(),
                mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017),
                dbName);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        String databaseName = "test"; // Replace with your desired database name
        String mongoUrl = getMongoUrl(databaseName);
        System.out.println("Connecting to MongoDB at: " + mongoUrl); // Log the connection URL
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(mongoUrl));
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        String mongoUrl = getMongoUrl("test"); // Same database name
        System.out.println("Creating MongoClient for: " + mongoUrl);
        return MongoClients.create(mongoUrl);
    }

    @Bean
    public GridFsOperations gridFsOperations(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return new GridFsTemplate(mongoTemplate.getMongoDbFactory(), mongoTemplate.getConverter());
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void stopContainer() {
        mongoDBContainer.stop();
    }
}


import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@WebMvcTest(AccountQueryController.class) // Replace with your actual controller class
public class AccountQueryControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    AccountQueryController accountQueryController;

    @Test
    public void searchByOrgAndGroupAndName_ShouldReturnAccounts() throws Exception {
        String query = "testQuery";

        mockMvc.perform(get("/byorgandgroupandname")
                        .param("query", query))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(greaterThan(0)))) // Assumes it returns a list
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("SampleName"))); // Replace with expected field
    }
}

Getting below error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Please add @DataMongoTest on top of AccountQueryControllerTest.
